# Site error: Accessing php project

Tags: php, html, xampp

I am facing below error on access any php page(except default) in root directory of xampp  page and I included the below  required dll in the project directory but following error is still  displayed.

```
Site error: the file C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php requires the ionCube PHP Loader ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the ionCube Loader Wizard to assist with installation.
```

Comment: Don't forget to add extension to php.ini

Comment: what  type extension are required in php.ini file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download loader from http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php , unpack it, and installer helps you to install it and tells you what exactly you should change.

Also you should install loaders that are compatible with your installation - VC11/VC9 or Non-TS/TS or 32bit/64 bit are the choices so you need to check if you installed correct loader

**Detailed instruction:**

Open http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php , and installed correct version in ZIP format, for example *Windows VC11 (32 bits)*. Unzip it and copy directory ioncube to C:\xampp\htdocs

Ensure you have xampp turned on

Now open `http://localhost/ioncube/loader-wizard.php` in your browser and you will get detailed instructions how to install, what should be fixed , where to copy files , what to edit and so on.

Comment: I Installed ioncube dll in project directory butt error is still displayed

Comment: Ioncube dlls should be rather installed in Apache  folder and not in your project directory

Comment: Error are still displaying  when I installed dll in apache folder

Comment: I've added detailed instruction to answer

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek has done a great job with an answer, but if still stuck, you can contact ioncu.be/S for guidance too.