# Wampserver install Ioncube error

Tags: php, wampserver, ioncube

I'm using Wampserver 2.5 Apache2.4 64bit, PHP 5.5 64bit and Ioncube PHP Loader v4.7.1 (Ioncube for PHP 5.5 vc11 ts)

When i test the encoded file i got "The connection was reset" error.

How do I make Ioncube work on Wampserver?

```
; Ioncube
zend_extension = "C:\wamp\bin\php\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll"
```

Ioncube TS or NonTS are same result.
Ioncube is in phpinfo(); but not working.
Slash (/) or Back slash(\) has same effect. not working.

Ioncube did have 64bit vc11 for PHP. please check at http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php

> Windows VC11 (64 bits)
>   Windows VC11 (Non-TS) (64 bits)

Comment: `ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll` What version is it? x64 bits with VC11 or VC9? Which version was used to compile Apache/PHP? TS or non-TS? Check error logs of the server.

Comment: Ioncube 64bit for PHP 5.5 64bit vc11 TS. no error log telling about this.

Comment: did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711069/site-error-accessing-php-project and TS or non-TS should correspond to the version of PHP that you have

Comment: Yes, i installed use loader wizard and it tell me that i was installed correctly but still error.
I change between TS or Non-TS but all error.

Comment: Do you see it listed in `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`?

Comment: It listed. I told you, loader wizard tell me that i was installed correctly.

Comment: Probably something is wrong with the encrypted file. Try another one.

Comment: All files encrypted via Ioncube encode online works perfectly with manual install apache php. as described in the question. so, i think there is nothing wrong with encrypted file but i thinks it's something wrong with Wampserver.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to do the same setup. Can you share encrypted file or where I can get any of them for testing?

Comment: And this is what I've got - http://oi59.tinypic.com/hu3vpw.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ioncube does not work with Apache+PHP 64 bit.

WampServer or manual install are not working.

Ioncube says that PHP 64 bit for Windows is currently experimental.

Comment: For avoidance of doubt, the official php.net Windows page (http://windows.php.net/download) says "Note: x64 builds are currently experimental", which is what ionCube is drawing your attention to. Performance results also tend to show that 64 bit PHP is slower than 32, and so unless you need to have a 64 bit implementation, it's likely best all round to go for 32 bit.  The above not withstanding, the VC11 64 bit Loaders from ionCube work well with the experimental 64 bit builds from php.net, but from your results, the WAMP 64 bit PHP offering may be incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

For WAMPServer all dll's must be compiled as Thread Safe (TS).

If you are using the 64bit version of WAMPServer then you need to download from the [ioncube site](https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php) the zip called `Windows VC11 (64 bits)`

All of which you seem to already know.

The only other thing I can think of is that the

```
zend_extension = "C:\wamp\bin\php\ioncube\ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll"
```

line should go at the bottom of php.ini, just before the XDEBUG parameters is where I put mine.

**Ah I think I spotted your error!!!!**

Think what PHP does with backslashes inside double quote!

Just change the `\` to `/` and you should be good to go.

```
zend_extension = "C:/wamp/bin/php/ioncube/ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll"
```

But remember you need the Thread Safe version for WAMPServer.

**REPEATED RECOMMENDATION**

As I said above: Please move the `zend_extension = "C:/wamp/bin/php/ioncube/ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll"` to the bottom of your `php.ini` file like this just before the `zend_extension` line for XDEBUG :-

```
; Local Variables:
; tab-width: 4
; End:

;ioncube Extension
zend_extension = "C:/wamp/bin/php/ioncube/ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll"

; XDEBUG Extension
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll"
```

Comment: Thread safe or Non Thread safe are same result. the connection was reset.

Comment: Yes, TS or NTS back slash \ or slash / nothing change still error.

Comment: Do you now see the IONCUBE registration info on a phpinfo().

Comment: Yes, sir. Ioncube is there in phpinfo();

Comment: Are you sure you have the TS version in `C:/wamp/bin/php/ioncube/` and of course restart Apache whenever you change whats in that file!!!

Comment: Yes, i was tried both of them before and everytime i change php.ini, i restart Apache.

Comment: Please IGNORE all the NON-TS dll's. For WAMPServer IT MUST BE **Thread Safe**

Comment: what i have http://i61.tinypic.com/10eevrc.jpg
in PHP.ini http://i62.tinypic.com/2igehi0.jpg

Comment: See additional info in my answer

Comment: Moved to the bottom before xdebug. Changed from \ to /. restarted apache.
but still error the connection was reset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64490/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-vee).